# Android - <include layout=.../> returns error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I have a library project in which I define an action bar in layout file `action_bar.xml` like this :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <LinearLayout style="@style/actionBar" />
    </merge>
```

The corresponding style element is this :

```
<style name="actionBar">
    <item name="android:id">@id/action_bar_container</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/title_height</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
</style>
```

When I try to include the action bar in another layout file `dashboard_activity_layout.xml` like below :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/CustomTheme"
    android:id="@+id/activity_dashboard_root_container" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/action_bar"/>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:padding="6dip">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It is continuously throwing the error :

`You must specifiy a valid layout reference. The layout ID @layout/action_bar is not valid.
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log`

I think this is a very simple problem and I'm missing a small detail. Any help is appreciated. I have adapted this from the Google I/O code. Does it have to do with the Library Project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though eclipse gave me this error. I was able to run the app which was using the library project and the behaviour seen was the expected one. I think this is something to do with eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a documented ADT bug [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21051) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21404) and still exists in ADT R16.

Answer (score 0):

@Promod, You have opened a Linear layout in Action_bar.xml. But you have not added any items inside the linear layout.

1. Linear layout needs minimum parameters like, layout_width, layout_height. Try adding them.

Comment: these parameters are coming from the style element.

Answer (score 0):

launch eclipse with the **-clean** option and your problem is fixed. It will take about 30 seconds longer to launch though